# How to properly forward Docker container port onto local host?

Tags: docker

I have a process running on a Docker container (an HP AutoPass License Server) that, after installation, says that its GUI can be accessed at https://<Host/IP address>:5814/autopass. I also have my Docker container configured to forward port 5814 to port 5040 on my local computer. However, when I go to https://:5040 on my browser, the connection times out (i.e. there is no process running on that port on my local computer). How can I fix this?

The command "ps aux" shows that the command is still running; started about twenty minutes ago. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:5040?

Comment: Just tried, no response.

Comment: Did you try `https://localhost:5040/autopass`?

Comment: How did you start the container?

Comment: https://localhost:5040/autopass worked, thank you! Honestly, it seems kind of an obvious solution now. Not sure how I missed it, but thank you.